# Run Spring batch with CommandLineJobRunner error impossible to find or load main class CommandLineJobRunner

Tags: jar, spring-batch

I am new to Spring batch and want to run a batch with a command line using CommandLineJobRunner class, So I copied the generated jar file and CommandLineJobRunner to my Desktop and after I ran the following command:

**Java -cp spring-batch-example.jar org.springframework.batch.core.launch. support. CommandLineJobRunner classpath: /jobs/file-import-job. xml simpleFileImportJob**

which give this error (impossible to find or load main org. springframework. batch. core. launch. support. CommandLineJobRunner).
I think that I should deal with the classpath, I don't know how doing it.

### [image] [image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to add Spring Batch jars to the classpath too, something like:

```
java -cp spring-batch-example.jar:lib/* org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner classpath:/jobs/file-import-job.xml simpleFileImportJob
```

where `lib` contains Spring Batch jars and their dependencies. Note that if you are on windows, you need to use ';' instead of ':' to separate classpath entries.

I recommend to use [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) or a similar plugin to create an uber jar, or use [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) and it will do it for you. In both cases, you would be able to run your job with:

```
java -jar spring-batch-example.jar
```

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud for the answer, i added spring batch jars  but i still have the same error, i edited the question to put screen shots

Comment: maven-shade-plugin create a jar with all dependencies required, so it solves my problem.

Comment: For Gradle use the gradle shadow plugin. This discussion show how to use it for spring specifically:  https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-use-the-gradle-shadow-plugin-to-merge-spring-handlers-and-spring-schemas-files-of-multiple-spring-jar-dependencies/6713/5

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot to build an uber jar, but I still want to call the CommandLineJobRunner and pass the job name of multiple possible jars defined within my app. If I just do `java -jar example-app.jar` it calls the default `@SpringBootApplication` class's `main` method. How do I use Boot and `CommandLineJobRunner` together?

Comment: I'm able to run `CommandLineJobRunner` from within IntelliJ and let it take care of building the full classpath, but I can't figure out how I'll run it after being built into a fat jar.